# QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Widget "", which already has a layout

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget

I'm trying to set the layout of a widget manually through code (not in Designer), but I'm doing something wrong, because I get this warning:

> QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Widget "", which already has a layout

And also the layout is messed up (the label is at the top, instead of the bottom).

This is an example code that reproduces the problem:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Test", this);
    QHBoxLayout *hlayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    QVBoxLayout *vlayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QSpacerItem *spacer = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    hlayout->addItem(spacer);
    hlayout->addWidget(lineEdit);
    vlayout->addLayout(hlayout);
    vlayout->addWidget(label);
    setLayout(vlayout);
}
```

Comment: WOW, all of this work on just a simple error: 


        QHBoxLayout *buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout(); 

instead of: 

        QHBoxLayout *buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);

Comment: Same with mine in PySide, changing hl = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self) to hl = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

Answer (score 19):

So I believe your problem is in this line:

```
QHBoxLayout *hlayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
```

In particular, I think the problem is passing `this` into the `QHBoxLayout`.  Because you intend for this `QHBoxLayout` to NOT be the top level layout of `this`, you should not pass `this` into the constructor.

Here's my re-write that I hacked into a test app locally and seems to work great:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Test");
    QHBoxLayout *hlayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    QVBoxLayout *vlayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    QSpacerItem *spacer = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
    hlayout->addItem(spacer);
    hlayout->addWidget(lineEdit);
    vlayout->addLayout(hlayout);
    vlayout->addWidget(label);
    setLayout(vlayout);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you are creating layouts with a parent of `this`. When you do that, it sets the layout to be the main layout of `this`. Thus, it is redundant to call `setMainLayout()`.