# How to eliminate this message QT

Tags: qt

Hi i did one project in qt but show me this message:

> QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QWidget "", which already has
>   a layout

How i can solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Widget "", which already has a layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519006/qwidgetsetlayout-attempting-to-set-qlayout-on-widget-which-already-has)

Answer (score 0):

Is Qt configured correctly?  This happened to me one time and it was a Qt error.  Try making a new project and see if the same thing happens.